# OpenLayers Vector layer not showing on the whole screen

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers

I have a Vector Layer on my OpenLayers map that doesn't take the whole screen and it's driving me crazy.
The layer in question shows POIs on the map, but only in a portion of the screen. When I move the map POIs get cut off in the middle as they reach the end of the layer.
However, when I **resize** the screen, everything gets back to normal.

Here's my layer :

```
POILayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(POIsLayresName, {
    'displayInLayerSwitcher': false,
    strategies: [strat, strategie],
    protocol: proto,
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": PoisStyle,
        "select": {
            fillColor: "#8aeeef",
            strokeColor: "#32a8a9"
        }
    }),
    rendererOptions: {
        yOrdering: true
    }
});

map.addLayers([POILayer]);
```

Knowing that the layer take the whole width but only a part the *height*, is there a way I can control it's *height* ?

Comment: Does it help if you call the [updateSize](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.updateSize) method on rendering the map/layer?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like a more sufficient technique.